# Facebook Audience Network: is Facebook Login required?

Tags: admob, facebook-android-sdk, facebook-ios-sdk, facebook-audience-network, mobile-ad-mediation

we've integrated Facebook Audience Network in our Android and iOS apps a few days ago. We're using AdMob Open Bidding mediation.

Technically speaking everything seems to be ok, the SDK is initializing as expected and the AdMob adapter has been integrated correctly.

However, right now Facebook is bidding on a very small percentage of our impressions (less than 5%), and the main reason seems to be the following according to the facebook dashboard: "no facebook profile found".

We were not expecting 100% of our users to have a facebook profile, but at least 50% let's say, 20-30% in the worst case. So there's clearly something here that isn't working as expected and that we're missing.

We've contacted their support and they told us that the users of our apps are required to login via Facebook in order for Audience Network to work, which sounds a little strange, since this is not mentioned anywhere in the official documentation. Also, we thought the advertising ID (IDFA on iOS) was more than enough to identify a user and track him across different apps.

So we were wondering: has anyone of you guys ever integrated Facebook Audience Network over AdMob (perhaps via Open Bidding)? If so, as far as you know, is Facebook Login really required?

Answer (score 3):

Speaking from my experience with several Android apps using FAN via Admob Mediation you can usually expect a fill rate between 75-80%, so 5% is suspiciously low. None of the apps I have integrated use Facebook Login or are specifically related to Facebook. They only use the Admob Adapter and nothing else.

Also, make sure that all your Properties are approved by Facebook (it takes a few days) and meet the Quality Check criteria as this might also cause cryptic error messages or low fill rates

*Fill Rates*
[image: Fill rates]
*No Fill Reasons*
[image: No Fill reasons]

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. You confirmed what we already thought, sometimes I wonder how the support can give this kind of "inaccurate" answers.

Comment: I'm doing the same as you (mediated open bidding via admob). We're also getting about 5% fill rate for FAN. Did your fill improve over time? I think the fill is different when not using bidding (classic waterfall seems to give higher fill for FAN).

Comment: Were you able to solve the problem? Since we use bidding, we only have a few percent fill.

Comment: @ekstro we ended up removing FAN, apparently there's an issue with bidding.

Comment: I have integrated FAN and have the same issue with bidding. Only 8% of them are filled. The main reason is also "No Facebook profile found". Did you guys somehow fix this issue?

Comment: I use ironsource and I have verry low bid rate. It's less than 1%
I wonder if it's still same for everyone on iOS.

Answer (score 1):

Actually your issue is "bid rate" not "fill rate". FAN show ads most to the facebook users. If a user is not logged in to facebook more than 30 days on that device, you'll probably end with this issue. For a successful "bid rate", make sure users of your app (for FAN) have logged in to facebook (your app/ facebook app) in the last 30 days.

For more info:
[Advanced app bidding tips and tricks](https://www.facebook.com/audiencenetwork/resources/blog/advanced-app-bidding-tips-and-tricks)